# How to execute SQL scripts stored in cells of a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, data-cleaning, dynamic-sql

I have a fairly complicated dynamic SQL script that outputs dozens of scripts into a temp table. For example:

| UpdateTables | AlterColumns |
| --- | --- |
| UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET zipcode = null where col = ''; | ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN zipcode INT; |
| UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET gender = null where col = ''; | ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN gender CHAR; |

As you can probably tell, the scripts generated are for clean up. It essentially goes into the specified table, grabs every column, and generates scripts to clean it up (alter variable type, trim column spaces, changes blanks to nulls, and renames columns at the end to be camel case).

The table (and the point I'm at now) has all the exact scripts I would need generated. I just need to find a way to execute those. I think I could use dynamic SQL, but using it with temp tables is a nightmare. I could alternatively store it as a table and then reference that in a new dynamic SQL, but that is also kind of messy. Any other options? Or what would be the best option in general?

Basically I need to generate something like this:

```
exec(
UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET zipcode = null where col = '';
UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET gender = null where col = '';       
ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN zipcode INT;
ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN gender CHAR;
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cells? Cells are spreadsheets, databases have rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating a `#tempTable` with the queries you want to run, you can quickly concatenate them into a string and execute them with `sp_executesql`.

```
drop table if exists #tmpTable;

create table #tmpTable (stmt nvarchar(max));
insert #tmpTable (stmt)
values ('UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET zipcode = null where col = '''';')
     , ('UPDATE mydb.sch.tbl SET gender = null where col = '''';')
     , ('ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN zipcode INT;')
     , ('ALTER TABLE mydb.sch.tbl ALTER COLUMN gender CHAR;');

declare @stmt nvarchar(max) = N'';
select @stmt = @stmt + stmt
  from #tmpTable;

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt;
```

But I'm pretty sure that you won't re-name the column if you don't change the name. That is to say: you can't change "ThisStyle" to "thisStyle" by using `alter column`.

Comment: Using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: Thanks @brian-stork , that worked perfectly I think! What do you mean by the renaming bit? In the alter column example above, I am changing the data type, not the column name. To rename the columns, I am using something like: EXEC SP_RENAME 'mySchema.myTbl.myOldColumn', 'my_new_column';  

I think this works - i just didn't show that in my original post. to keep things simpler.

Comment: @thomA Thanks, My sql version does support String_AGG. I tried it with my temp table and it works for one column but not multiple.....is there a way to aggregate strings from multiple columns?

What worked:
Select STRING_AGG(colA, ';')

What did NOT work:
Select STRING_AGG(colA,  colB, colC, ';')

Comment: You need to *concatenate* values from different columns, @manavjn . Otherwise unpivot the values and then aggregate.